# Update form error - Spring4 mvc - org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create update form using Spring mvc. Once user click the update button it shows the current values in input tags. When I edit the current values and hit the submit button it shows the following error.

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleTypeMismatch
>       WARNING: Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "updateStudent"

**home.jsp**

```
<form:form method="GET" action="updateStudent" commandName="selectedUser">
        <table>

            <tr>
                <form:input path="userID" placeholder="userID"
                    value="${selectedUsers.userID}" />
                <form:input path="userName" placeholder="userName"
                    value="${selectedUsers.userName}" />
                <form:input path="password" placeholder="password"
                    value="${selectedUsers.password}" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

**controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updateStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String updateStudent(@ModelAttribute("selectedUser") User user, 
        ModelMap model) throws Exception {

    Student student = new Student();
    System.out.println("come here helloController()");
    model.addAttribute("userID", user.getUserID());
    model.addAttribute("userName", user.getUserName());
    model.addAttribute("password", user.getPassword());
    model.addAttribute("student",student);
    model.addAttribute("user",user);
    System.out.println("student id is " + user.getUserID());
    // model.addAttribute("userI", user);
    if (user.getUserID() == 0) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "please enter id");
        return "home";
    }
    if (user.getUserName() == null) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "please enter getUserName");
        return "home";
    }
    if (user.getPassword() == null) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "please enter getPassword");
        return "home";
    }
    return "home";
}
```

**User.java**

```
public class User {
    int userID;
    String userName;
    String password;

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I need to pass the updated values to controller. Hope you got the question. Please help to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your model class `User` have the attribute `int id` which is primitive type data. change it to `Interger` object.

```
Integer userID;
```

along with getter and setter. everything will be fine I think.

Comment: Clean and build your project and run again. Your exception tells that this is the reason.

Comment: Did you put any string except number in `userID` field ? @dmaprasad